# Appropriate decorator for angular base service with lifecycle hooks?

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I've got a service base class that implements `OnDestroy` to clean up an internal Subject:

```
export abstract class BaseService implements OnDestroy {
  private subject = new Subject<void>();
  constructor( ... ) { }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subject.complete();
  }
}
```

This base class is intended explicit construction via child class calling `super(...)`, and has parameters that cannot be provided by dependency injection.

The child classes are intended to singleton angular services:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChildService extends BaseService {
  constructor() {
    /* manually build and provide constructor parameters to base */
    super(...);
  }
}
```

However, as of Angular version 10, even base or abstract classes that implement lifecycle hooks must be properly decorated, as denoted by the following error message:

`Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.`

I don't mind adding a decorator to get it recognized properly by the Angular infrastructure.  However, of the four class decorators I know, none seem appropriate to use for the base class.

`@Component` and `@NgModule` are explicitly incorrect.  `@Injectable` is close, but then it tries and fails to evaluate the base class's constructor for dependency injection, giving other errors (requesting the constructor parameters to be marked with the appropriate `@Inject` decorators).

`@Directive` seems to work without complaint, but this seems like a misuse of the decorator, and I wonder what kind of overhead is being added.

Is there a recommended solution for this pattern?

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario, the recommended decorator to use is `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` on your abstract base class `BaseService`.
You can then use this decorator on your child services as well.

The issue you encountered with this decorator trying to evaluate the base class's constructor for dependency injection can be resolved by marking the constructor parameters in the base class with the @Optional() decorator. This indicates that the parameters are optional and should not be injected, allowing you to manually provide them in the child service constructor.

Here's an example of how your `BaseService` class should look with the `@Injectable` decorator and optional constructor parameters:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export abstract class BaseService implements OnDestroy {
  private subject = new Subject<void>();
  
  constructor(@Optional() private dependency1: Dependency1, @Optional() private dependency2: Dependency2) {
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subject.complete();
  }
}
```

And your child service would look like:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChildService extends BaseService {
  constructor(private dependency1: Dependency1, private dependency2: Dependency2) {
    super(dependency1, dependency2);
  }
}
```

With this setup, your base service can be properly decorated as an injectable, and you can manually provide constructor parameters for both the base and child services.

**UPDATE**

If marking the base class constructor parameters with the `@Optional()` decorator is still resulting in a compilation error, it's possible that the issue is related to the fact that you're using lambdas for the parameters.

In that case, you can try using the `InjectionToken` class to provide the dependencies in the child class constructor. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export abstract class BaseService implements OnDestroy {
  private subject = new Subject<void>();
  constructor(private dep1: any, private dep2: any) { }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subject.complete();
  }
}

export const DEP1 = new InjectionToken<any>('dep1');
export const DEP2 = new InjectionToken<any>('dep2');

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChildService extends BaseService {
  constructor(@Inject(DEP1) dep1: any, @Inject(DEP2) dep2: any) {
    super(dep1, dep2);
  }
}
```

In the above code, we've defined two `InjectionToken` objects, one for each dependency. Then in the child class constructor, we use the `@Inject()` decorator to inject the dependencies using the tokens.

To provide the dependencies, you can use the providers array in the `@NgModule` decorator of your module:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: DEP1, useValue: /* provide the dependency here */ },
    { provide: DEP2, useValue: /* provide the dependency here */ }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

With this approach, you should be able to provide the dependencies to the base class constructor, even if they're lambdas, without running into any compilation errors.

Comment: This sounded like a great solution, but using `@Optional()` here still grants a compilation error of `No suitable injection token for parameter 'dependency1' of class BaseService`.  Notably, in my specific case, the base class constructor has lambdas for parameters.

Comment: @Serge I just updated my post. :) Hopefully it works.